# iOS6 passbook pass update through Apns_PHP push notification is not playing sound, independent of phone settings

Tags: php, ios6, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I am testing the `ApnsPHP_Push` object as indicated in the example documents.
The APNS notification reaches the device, but I can't manage to hear a sound, no mater how I configure  the message with setSound();

I tried:

- not calling setSound();
- calling setSound();
- calling setSound('default');
  -calling setSound('chimes');

I also worked through the settings in 2 different iPhones, enabling and disabling the alternatives in the notifications settings, with no success.
Is it possible the pass needs some configuration that could be missing to enable sound notifications or, for instance, in this case, a coupon pass can not receive sound notifications?

I am using latest version of iOS 6.0.1 with an iPhone 3GS.

Thank you!

Addendum:
I received this reply from [Apple's developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com)

"Pass push notifications are different to App push notifications in that the push merely serves as a notification to tell the device to contact the webServiceURL and request that the updated pass be sent.  App pushes contain a payload of new data that is instantly displayed when the push arrives.

Your push should contain an empty payload as per the documentation - your sound is most likely being ingnored by device. Your best bet is to file a feature request to see if sounds can be supported in a future release, but as on now, it is not possible to trigger a sound for a pass update."

Comment: This is correct, since the payload is empty you cannot specify a sound to play. I doubt Apple will ever allow this since as you also state, the push itself has nothing to show or say. When your push arrives Passbook wakes up and asks your server what passes have changed. You return the changed passes when asked and then Passbook will create local notifications if you supplied a changeMessage field as per the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the post on the Apple Dev Forums, and it still stands as of the latest 6.1 beta build.

You cannot trigger an audible alert for a Passbook pass.